# Silverlight saving to Wordpress Database

Tags: database, silverlight, wordpress, joomla, settings

I have a wordpress database for accounts and settings (or for this example, joomla accounts and settings database).

I also have a working silverlight application that works all by itself without problems.

How can I have the two communicate? For example, the user should be able to log on to my silverlight application using my wordpress/joomla DB. Also, any settings should be able to be saved onto the user's account on the website.

Is this possible? If so, how?

As of now, I am using Isolated Storage however, when the application needs to be loaded at another location, I want to be able to open the same settings as on my home PC.

How could this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Services would be the way to go, but I don't know what your hosting restrictions are?